# Hive create table with lots of columns

Tags: hive

What would be the best way to create a Hive table with lots of columns(String)(>100) from a huge file with pipe separators.

1. Will it be a problem if I mention more than 100 column names in my create table command.
2. If I decide I don't want to name each columns can I a) Not mention the column names at all and let Hive name the column names as per its default naming. How would I do that b) Mention only some of the columns say first 10. In this case what will happen to to remaining columns?
   I tried it this way:

   ```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    LOCATION 'folder1/folder2/folder3/filename';
   ```

I get an error saying 'Either list of columns or a custom serializer should be specified'. Do I need a custom serializer for it?
If the external table doesn't have partitions, how do I add partitions?

Comment: you can probably do that in apache drill or impala

Comment: It might work if you create a sort of import table that has only one string column and reference the file this way. Then you could use a `create table as` statement with a query that uses maybe split to generate an array out of the string and then with an explode statement convert it into a table. Shooting from the hip here though...

Answer (score 0):

1. create a generic script for table creation in hive.
   here take delimiter ,path ,table name and schema dynamically using hiveconf

   create table ${hiveconf:tablename}(${hiveconf:schema}) 
   row format delimited fields terminated by '${hiveconf:delimiter}' 
    location '${hiveconf:location}';
2. write a shell script for running that above script

   hive -hiveconf tablename=$1 -hiveconf schema=$2 -hiveconf delimiter=$3 -hiveconf location=$4 -f abovefilpath.q

3.pass parameters to shell script and run the shell script

```
sh secondstepshellscriptpath urtblname schema details urdelimiter hdfspath
```

With above approach you can create a table for any number columns and it is highly reusable.

Here You Prepare schema with some other tool which will produce output something like below ..

```
"col1 string,sol2 string,col3 string,col4 string etc..."
```

for example you can generate above output within  shell script by taking number of columns dynamically from user.And you can directly pass that schema from 2nd step itself directly.

Comment: This does not answer either of his questions. The approach only makes a person avoid having to type part of the command syntax to create a table.

Comment: OP isn't asking how to reduce his work in writing create statements. He's asking how to define it in either partially structured or unstructured manner.